# How to access android annotation sharedPreference?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences, android-annotations

I am using `Android annotation` to create `SharedPreferences` in Android project.

## AppPreferences

```
public interface CommonPref {
@DefaultString("")
String deviceId();

@DefaultString("NA")
String clientId();

@DefaultString("NA")
String accessToken();

@DefaultString("NA")
String refreshToken();

@DefaultString("NA")
String devToken();
}
```

When I am trying to access or filling these values from a class extended by `android.app.Application` It's throwing an error. Here is my code:

```
SuppressLint("Registered")
@EApplication
public class SampleApp extends Application {

public static CommonPref_ cprefs;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    cprefs = new CommonPrefs_(this);
}
```

I thought it's related to `Applicaiton` because `Android annotation` is the last process to execute when we build the project (may be before than Applicaiton files).

I tried to access the `preference` in activity file but it's throwing me same error i.e. `Error:(25, 5) error: cannot find symbol class CommonPref_`

The steps I followed to integrate it:

- Downloaded the dependencies
- Wrote the interface for preferences

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Use @Pref in SampleApp class instead of instantiating generated pref.

```
@Pref
CommonPref_ cprefs;
```

Access deviceId by using

```
cprefs.deviceId().get();
```